# In Spring Boot Application, annotation based pointcut is not executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

Hi I have created spring boot application and trying to apply Aspect using spring AOP. The code is as below ...

The custom Timer annotation

```
package org.my.pckg.annotation;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Timer {
}
```

The TimerLoggingAspect Aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TimeLoggingAspect {

@Pointcut("annotation(@org.my.pckg.annotation.Timer)")
public void loggingPointCutDefinition(){}

    @Around("loggingPointCutDefinition()")
    public void userAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable{
        createJsonString(joinPoint);
        joinPoint.proceed();
    }

    private String createJsonString(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    //logic for creating and printing json
        return "";
    }
}
```

The config class

```
package org.my.pckg.config;
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy  
@ComponentScan(basePackages =     {"org.my.pckg.utilities","org.my.pckg.annotation"})
public class AssetConfig {

    @Bean
    public TimeLoggingAspect timeLoggingAspect() {
        return new TimeLoggingAspect();
    }
}
```

The Example test controller

```
package org.my.pckg;
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.my.pckg.config","org.my.pckg.annotation"})
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Example {

@Timer
@RequestMapping("/")
String home() {
    return "Hello World!";
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Example.class, args);
}
}
```

And the `application.properties` contains the following:

```
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true
```

With the above setting when I bebug the application using:

```
spring-boot:run "-Drun.jvmArguments=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

The Aspect is not executed but if I change the pointcut
from   `@Around("@annotation(org.my.pckg.annotation.Timer)")`
 to     `@Around("execution( * org.my.pckg.*.*(..))")`
It works perfectly!

Please help to find out what's missing in defining custom annotation..

Answer (score 2):

Change your pointcut from:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@org.my.pckg.annotation.Timer)")
```

To:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(org.my.pckg.annotation.Timer)")
```

Read the Spring Documentation on [Declaring a Pointcut](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-pointcuts).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.. I have tried @annotation option and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After many trial and error I found a solution for the above problem.

Create a file aop.xml and put it inside resource /META-INF/ with following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aspectj>
<!-- place all aspects here -->
<aspects>
    <aspect name="<full qualified name of aspect class>"/>
</aspects>
<weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
</weaver>
```

Thanks to http://foat.me
Find more detailed solution here
http://foat.me/articles/java-aspects-using-spring-aop-and-aspectj/#internal-method-calls